# When programatically creating a ViewController, how can I set its view to be of type SKVIew?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, transition

I am developing a game in iOS on XCode. I have several SKScenes each associated with a UIViewController class. So in each of the view controller's viewDidLoad, I create

```
SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view
SKScene * scene = [whateverSKScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size]
[skView present scene]
```

I want to avoid the storyboard. However, when I presentViewController from the first view controller to the next, the app crashes at the line "[skView present scene]" because it thinks the new view controller's view is still UIView ('-[UIView presentScene:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance).

How can I fix this? Specifically, when creating the 2nd view controller (programatically), how can I change its view to be of type SKview not UIview?
(I should note I want the scenes to be 1:1 with view controllers because almost all of them are popups like a pause-menu pop up over game play or settings pop up etc)

Comment: How do you create the second view controller.  If you aren't using storyboard/nib then it is up to you to create the SKView and assign it as the view - you can't just retrieve it

Comment: view controller is created and presented in the first view controller like:

UIVIewController *test = [[MyViewController2 alloc] init];
[self presentViewController: test animated: YES];

Comment: So then in the initialiser for the view controller you are responsible for the allocation of an SKView and assigning it to the view property of the controller.

Comment: I've managed to conclude that, but to the best of my knowledge, my solution doesn't work (below). How would I allocate the SKview? The result below just animates over my current screen with a grey screen.

UIVIewController *test = [[MyViewController2 alloc] init]; 
test.view = [[SKView alloc] init];
[self presentViewController: test animated: YES];

Comment: No, you need to modify the`init` method of your custom UIViewController subclass to initialise your SKView

Comment: Why are you using multiple VCs ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try implementing the loadView method on your custom ViewController, like so:

```
override func loadView() {
        self.view = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480))
}
```

This is what Apple's documentation states:

> This is where subclasses should create their custom view hierarchy if
>   they aren't using a nib. Should never be called directly.

Comment: You should use `UIScreen.mainScreen.applicationFrame` instead of a hardcoded rectangle.